# How to pass an hex value as string and put it in char variable?

Tags: c, cmd, hex, memory-address

Maybe what I'm asking for is not feasible but I will try to make as clear as possible.

I have a simple file written in c. when I execute it, I pass a string by command line and store it in a local variable in the main function.

The string in memory is convert in exadecimal like this:

es. main ABCDEFGH
in the stack we will see 0x44434241 0x48474645

what about the inverse problem? I want to find a string (or number) such that the memory appears in a manner i.e 0xab640e17 0x45b2c78a (arbitrary hexadecimal value)

Consider that I want all this by command line, no code improvement! Is there any special command or escape char for doing that?

Thanks, i hope it is clear enough :/

**possible solution**
maybe passing this: `perl -e 'print "\xab\x64\x0e\x17\x45\xb2\xc7\x8a"'`

Comment: Can you elaborate more the inverse case? I didn't get what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can just escape literal hex values in a C string like this:

```
const char * s = "\xab\x64\x0e\x17\x45\xb2\xc7\x8a";
```

or you can just use hex values directly like this:

```
const unsigned char s[8] = { 0xab, 0x64, 0x0e, 0x17, 0x45, 0xb2, 0xc7, 0x8a };
```

(which also has the advantage of not generating a trailing 0x00, if you don't actually need it).

Comment: I've tried to pass a string like yours, but it converts every single character in hex

Comment: example: if I pass "\xab" it converts in 0x6261785c

Comment: 0x5c = '\'. Are you storing input characters in ints instead of bytes?  Share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think you are just looking for an [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/).   Just look up each hex value and get the corresponding character.  Unfortunately, hex digits over 0x7F have machine-dependant  ASCII representations, and some of the lower values are not printable.

Comment: thanks, but as you said, some hex value belongs to non-printable characters

Comment: Right. So A) it's not possible to find a human readable string corresponding to every possible series of hex digits.  B) If you want to input from the command line, you need an encoding scheme.  You can use Paul R's, but you need to double escape the backslashes.